# How to disable PasswordBreachAgent

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, launchd

I use macOS Big Sur 11.7.2.

I first tried this in the Terminal (Bash, not zsh):

```
launchctl disable PasswordBreachAgent
```

Which generates this:

> Unrecognized target specifier.  takes a form of /.
> Please refer to `man launchctl` for explanation of the  specifiers.
> Usage: launchctl disable

After browsing the web, I tried to change the path to where this process is located and ran the above command again, but it did not work, it generated the same error. Here is what I did:

```
ps -ef | grep PasswordBreachAgent
```

This to find the PATH and then change it via:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<The path from above>
```

And I ran the following:

```
launchctl disable PasswordBreachAgent
```

The error persists. Then I tried this:

```
launchctl disable PasswordBreachAgent /<Path>
```

of course, it didn't work too the same error shows up.

Does someone know how can I disable this service? Or at least, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: First tell us why you want to disable PasswordBreachAgent. Also, which version of macOS are you running? Please update the question with all the relevant info..

Comment: @AndyGriffiths I updated the question. The why is personal, nothing technical.

Comment: Also, changing PATH won‘t help, where exactly did you get that from?

Comment: @nohillside From Linux. But here in this exchange, there was an answer once, which is not yet elected as the answer.

Comment: A link may help. Maybe the answer you found is poorly written and just needs fixing.

Comment: @nohillside I think I provide enough details and explanations for my problem which is very specific and on topic.

Comment: Nobody is questioning the validity of your question. But you seem to have found some unhelpful instructions on this site. Fixing those will help both you and future visitors of this site.

Comment: Also, the full error message you get actually includes the usage instructions and a reference to `man launchtl` for further instructions (and an explanation of `<domain-target>`).